# Batch ttf files to per-glyph-image

Tags: python, fonts, dataset, typography

I have a big dataset of google fonts in ttf file format.

I'd like to convert all their glyphs into individual images, how would I do this?

I found [this DrawBot script](https://gist.github.com/frankrolf/a4601673207d2a84e8027c7b91d60620), but it only allows for a single ttf file to be converted.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility to make it using fontforge. You need to [install it](https://fontforge.org/en-US/) for you OS first.

Here's the code adapted from [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1337567/how-do-i-convert-a-ttf-into-individual-png-character-images). Let's call the file ttf2pngs.py.

```
import os
from fontforge import *

font = open(os.sys.argv[1])
for glyph in font:
    if font[glyph].isWorthOutputting():
        font[glyph].export(font[glyph].glyphname + ".png")
```

Don't be alarmed by "package not found" warning on fontforge import. Fontforge knows about Python when you run it's commands from the terminal. You can run your script from the terminal as:

```
fontforge -script ttf2pngs.py YOURFONT.ttf
```

If you want to make it for several fonts in your folder, you can also create a separate Python script like the following (also adding destination folder in the script above):

```
import os

fonts = os.listdir(FOLDER_FONTS)
for font in fonts:
    os.makedirs(FOLDER_LETTERS + font.split(".")[0], exist_ok=True)
    os.system('cmd /c "fontforge -lang=py -script ttf2pngs.py %s %s"' % (FOLDER_FONTS + font, FOLDER_LETTERS))
```

Comment: When I try and run ttf2pngs.py I get the following error message:  
```The following table(s) in the font have been ignored by FontForge
 Ignoring 'DSIG' digital signature table
Application built with libpng-1.4.12 but running with 1.6.37
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joeparkerrees/ffglyph.py", line 6, in <module>
    F[name].export(filename)
OSError: Could not create image file ".notdef.png"```